# Galaxybase client prompt: "This driver instance has already been closed"

Tags: graph-databases

I’m a beginner in Graph Database and I’m using a Graph Database called Galaxybase. When I tried to call the driver, the client prompt: This driver instance has already been closed”.

Another thread also called the driver. Is there some action done on that thread that is causing my problem. If so, what it can be and how I can fix it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Driver object has already been closed and cannot be used anymore.The reasons could be:

1. Another thread called the close method of the Driver, causing an exception when the current thread made a call.
2. Another Graph object called the close method, synchronously closing the Driver object, causing an exception to the current Graph object that references the same Driver object.
3. The Driver was in the "try with resource" code block, causing an implicit call to the close method after execution.

In brief, the Driver object becomes unavailable by actively or passively calling the close method.

Please review code logic and see if there is any active or passive call to the close method.